# How can I convert a file (pdf/doc) served at a url into json / string / base64 format without downloading on local?

Tags: javascript, file, pdf, browser-cache, file-conversion

Let's say a pdf document is served at a url, ex - https://www.polyu.edu.hk/iaee/files/pdf-sample.pdf

I need to run a javascript that takes the url and makes a post request to a server with the pdf file data that can be converted back to file. Typical solutions for accessing files on a server location are around downloading on local first and then having the user upload it. How can we bypass the user interference ? Appreciate all inputs and workarounds like using browser cache / local storage etc.

Thanks

Comment: _"Typical solutions for accessing files on a server location are around downloading on local first and then having the user upload it."_, umm no that is not a typical solution, a typical solution would be for the server to download the file directly. There is no need to use a user as a middleman

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

JavaScript executed in a browser runs on the client machine. Thus any modification on a remote resource must be downloaded, modified and uploaded to the server.

As you already stated: using a browser cache or *local* storage wont help you.

You have to do this modifications on server-side e.g. with a servlet or php. You will need access to the server.